# Generics and Inheritance Problem

Tags: c#, design-patterns, generics, inheritance

I'm tempted to say this problem is with my general architecture but either way it's probably easier to show as an example than it would be to describe.

```
public class AppUserBase
{
}

public class AppUserAbc : AppUserBase
{
}

public class ManagerBase<T> where T : AppUserBase
{
    protected AppUserCollection<T> _users = new AppUserCollection<T>();
}

public class ManagerAbc : ManagerBase<AppUserAbc>
{

}

public static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        ManagerAbc x = new ManagerAbc();
        DoSomething(x); //fails
    }

    public static void DoSomething<M,U>(ManagerBase<AppUserBase> manager) where M : ManagerBase<U> where U : AppUserBase
    {
        //do something!
    }
}
```

I hope what I'm trying to do is easy to see and what I should be doing is even easier to explain to me :-).

Comment: This code doesn't even compile.  There is no Manager<> class in your code.  And what is the error it gives you?  Is it compile-time or run-time?  We need more information, Chris.

Comment: Also, C# 3.0 or 4.0? 4.0 has better co-variance / contra-variance support, which may be a factor here.

Comment: Sorry, it was meant to be ManagerBase not Manager. I have modified the post. Also, C# 4.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you have two type parameters but only one is in the method signature, so it can't infer both.  The other is not needed.  Change your method signature to:

```
public static void DoSomething<U>(ManagerBase<U> manager)
    where U : AppUserBase
{
    //do something!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That want work, as you probably know. The reason is that `ManagerAbc` is not of type `ManagerBase<AppUserBase>`. It doesn't help that the generic part is of the same type. You could try to change to:

```
public static void DoSomething<M,U>(ManagerBase<U> manager) where M : Manager<U> where U : AppUserBase
```

Comment: This does not compile.  M is not in the method signature and thus cannot be inferred.

Comment: @yoda: It won't compile if he call it like he does, but he can explicitly tell which types to use when making the call. However, `M` should be removed if it is not used, and it seems like it isn't in the example.

Comment: We are in agreement.  (I wanted to say "yep", but the stupid character limit...)